# may, might, would

Tags: grammar

Please let me know if "would" and "may" can be used in the following sentence instead of "might"?

> But despite these interpersonal elements, some students find it more difficult to sustain their motivation online than they **might** as part of a real learning group.

Comment: Please include more detail than you have provided.  Which do you think works, and why, and what research have you done to support your opinion?

Comment: This is unrelated to the actual question, but there's nothing *unreal* about online learning groups. (So, at least semantically, the sentence is a bit odd.)

Comment: I think "would" can be used instead, too. In the sentence, "would" implies imaginary certainty, "might" implies weak possibility and "may" implies strong possibility. But, I do not understand why the writer has used "might".

Comment: @Andrew I did research on uses of "may", "might", "will" and "would". I found out that the only modal used for thinking of imaginary hypothetical unreal situations is "would". With regards to the sentences, I think it resembles the following sentences : "Pairwork and groupwork are often used in large classes to give students more chances for interaction than they would get with whole-class teaching." Thus I think I would use 'would' rather than 'might'. I do not understand the reason why the writer has used 'might'.

Comment: @Jason Bassford I did research on uses of "may", "might", "will" and "would". I found out that the only modal used for thinking of imaginary hypothetical unreal situations is "would". With regards to the sentences, I think it resembles the following sentences : "Pairwork and groupwork are often used in large classes to give students more chances for interaction than they would get with whole-class teaching." Thus I think I would use 'would' rather than 'might'. I do not understand the reason why the writer has used 'might'.